# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion

I wonder what improvements to my [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33018/calculation-of-the-right-hand-side-of-dg-fem-with-code) could be made. Since it got some views, but no comments that ask for further details. It is aimed towards the readers of a certain book of which some certainly exist in this community. I am confident about this, because a search for the authors/book tilte yield some results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SciComp and its meta. I think your question is well-posed (pun intended) and should be eligible for an answer. However, please bear in mind that the SciComp community is not as large as StackOverflow or Mathematics. That means that it might take a bit longer for your question to get answered.